# Campo DateTime é nulo ao passar para o controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc, datetime, datepicker

Eu tenho em minha aplicação um formulário de pesquisa usando AjaxBeginForm.
No mesmo eu possuo um campo data (DateTime), e no qual eu estou usando o **bootstrap datePicker**.

Meu form está assim:

```
                            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Pedido", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divPedidos" }, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
                            {
                                @Html.TextBox("pesquisarRascunhoId", 0, new { style = "display: none" })
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <p>Data emissão</p>
                                        <div class="input-group date col-sm-5">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PedidoFilter.EmissaoInicial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm datepicker" } })
                                        </div>
                                        a
                                        <div class="input-group date col-sm-5">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PedidoFilter.EmissaoFinal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm datepicker" } })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="btn-search">
                                    <p class="demo-button">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-search"></i><span>Pesquisar</span></button>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            }
```

Meu javaScript para formatar a minha data em dd/mm/yyyy está assim:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        language: "pt-BR",
        autoclose: true
    });
```

Minha entidade está assim:

```
public class PedidoFilter
{
    public DateTime? EmissaoInicial { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EmissaoFinal { get; set; }
}
```

E por fim meu controller está assim:

```
    public ActionResult Index(PedidoResult pedidoResult, 
    {
        var pedido = _service.FindAll(pedidoResult.PedidoFilter);

        return View(pedido);
    }
```

1 - Todos os campos do meu formulário chegam no meu controller, porém meus campos de data são sempre nulos, no formato **dd/mm/yyyy**, que define no meu js do datepicker.

2 - Se eu inserir uma data no formato mm/dd/yyyy ela é passada para o meu controller.

Minha pergunta é:

Como posso passar meu campo de data no formato dd/mm/yyyy e recebe-los em meu controller, sem que os mesmos sejam nulos?

Comment: Você só precisa trocar a cultura da aplicação. Você está usando Owin ou as configurações estão no global.asax?

Comment: Não estou usando Owin. Eu define minha cultura no meu web config: **<globalization uiCulture="pt-BR" culture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />**

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que pode ser o mesmo problema que tive a pouco tempo, quando eu ia enviar o valor ele barrava pelo fato do formato ser diferente.

Você poderia fazer desta forma:

```
$(Element).val().split('/').reverse().join('/');
```

Isso eu acredito que resolve o seu problema.

Comment: Isso não funciona pra mim